# Wrap async task into DispatchWorkItem in Swift to make it cancellable?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, dispatch-queue, dispatchworkitem

I have a class with async methods. All the methods are the simplest:

```
class SomeClass {
   func someFunc(params: SomeParams, completion: ((SomeResult) -> ())?) {
      ... //some code where completion is called asynchronously, not only with DispatchQueue.async
   }
   ...//other methods
}
```

Now I need to add a possibility to cancel such these tasks but `SomeClass` is not responsible for it so such code should be placed into another class outside `SomeClass`. They recommend to use `DispatchWorkItem` but how wrap such async calls into it correctly?

Note: there are questions and answers how to replace `DispatchQueue.global().async` with `DispatchWorkItem`, not about wrapping existing tasks

Comment: Switch to “async await” the ability to cancel is built in and seamless if you are setup correctly.

Comment: @Rob currently I solved this with `Combine` and its `AnyCancellable` - like with `Concurrency` you suggest. But I hoped I don't need to switch from GCD to another framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you’ve solved your problem already, but for the sake of future readers and in answer to the titular question whether you can “Wrap async task into `DispatchWorkItem` in Swift to make it cancellable?”, the answer is that, no, simply wrapping it inside a `DispatchWorkItem` is generally not sufficient. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780910-cancel) tells us (emphasis added):

> Cancellation causes future attempts to execute the work item to return immediately. *Cancellation does not affect the execution of a work item that has already begun.*

If you `cancel` a `DispatchWorkItem` that you have already started, it merely sets [`isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780829-iscancelled) property of that `DispatchWorkItem` that you could check within some computationally intensive routine. But for many asynchronous tasks (like network requests), that would be of limited utility.

Worse, `DispatchWorkItem` is not well suited to wrap a task that is, itself, asynchronous. The `DispatchWorkItem` will generally finish the work item as soon as the asynchronous task has been launched, not waiting for it to complete (unless you do something kludgy and brittle, like using semaphores; so much so that it would best be considered an anti-pattern).

You really need to incorporate the cancelation logic within `someFunc`. Historically, we often reached for [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) subclasses (build upon the GCD framework) because we can then override `cancel` to trigger the cancelation of the asynchronous task. Or nowadays we might reach for the automatic cancelation propagation offered by [Swift concurrency’s](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency) `async`-`await`. Or, you appear to have achieved this with [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/).

So, bottom line, it depends upon what `someFunc` was doing, but `DispatchWorkItem` is often of limited utility, despite its (very basic) cancelation support.

Comment: if you started to speak about `async-await` could you please post an example?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/36faa190516c95da1b92d6f43e6573dd.